# How to create dynamic 2D text overlay that follows and tracks objects like this example

Tags: edit-mode, video, 2d

Does anyone know how to create a text overlay that seems to track and extend to the objects it's pointing to like in this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qz8i43E2tk4 I'm not sure what program they've used but I'd like to do the same thing in Blender. I've seen a few object tracking tutorials on youtube but I'm not sure how you could set it up so the arrows extend with a text box attached. Thank you in advance!

Comment: you could just parent them to the camera. Should work.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'm a bit unsure about what you mean as I was trying to add the text after the render. I'll have a look at adding text in the model which is what I think you mean.

Comment: you are right. I misunderstood you, sorry.

Comment: No worries Chris! I just wanted to do it in post production as my client may need it translated into a few languages. If anyone else can point me in the right direction let me know. Thanks again